# How to load image data from resource bitmap file for directshow filter?

Tags: c++, opencv, directshow

I need put one bitmap image to my directshow filter. Then user can use this bitmap image and do not care where is it.

First, I import this bitmap file into resource bundle, and get one IDB_BITMAP1.

Then, I need to read this IDB_BITMAP1 using opencv cvLoadImage or some windows image API to load this image into buffer.

So question is how to do this ?

Or is that possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I never tried it myself, but I believe you can use [Loadbitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145033%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [GetBitmapBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144850%28VS.85%29.aspx) to do this:

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = LoadBitmap(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));
GetBitmapBits(hBitmap, size, pBits);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know OpenCV, but the Win32 APIs [`LoadImage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045(VS.85).aspx) can load from resources as well. E.g.:

```
LoadImage(hInstance, 
          MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1),
          IMAGE_BITMAP,
          /*...*/);
```